# Crystal Report Viewer for Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I want to install Crystal Report viewer for Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 7 (64-bit PC). Available Report Viewer in SAP website supports Windows 8.1 and later versions.

Internet resources point to the latest CR Viewer.

Please let me know from where to get CR Viewer for VS 2013 (Windows 7 64-bit PC).

Comment: Just curious, you know that neither Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013, nor that version of Crystal Report Viewer are supported anymore. Any particular reason why you are trying to find an old version of an add-on for an old version of software to run on an old OS?

Comment: Anyway, https://www.thereportviewer.com/applications/report-viewer/old-installers these are the only versions you can obtain installers for AFAIK. Hope you want a version that is 8.0 or higher... If you're OK with copycats, there are other solutions out there... https://www.recrystallize.com/merchant/chelsea/cview.htm

Comment: @TylerH, not sure who you re connected to. Ken's website is de-facto standard for Crystal reports related tools. Here is a comparison of the Crystal viewers: http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/crystal-reports-viewers. Most of them support Windows 7

Comment: @Lan I don't follow. Connected to? Regarding Windows 7, it doesn't matter if people still support 4th party software, the 1st and 3rd party software itself is not supported anymore.